# Javascript Confirm Delete in One PHP File (on href)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, confirmation

```
<p><span class="linky"><a href="deletephone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete Phone</a></span></p><br />
```

I have the above code that I am using to link to a delete script.
I want to somehow incorporate Javascript with a simple onclick confirmation. This way if they choose OK, I can run the code to delete the item from the database, but if they choose Cancel then I can cancel the operation and do nothing.

I have tried a whole variety of functions with changing the window.location to the delete file, and trying to cancel the href= if they choose Cancel, but it always goes to the link regardless of what the user clicks.

I would like to be able to keep the delete functions inside the same PHP file if possible, but this is not necessary at all.

Thanks in advance!

ASIDE: If there is a simple PHP way to check IF the alert was confirmed or denied, that could work also. Any way to check what the user chooses and then run my simple delete PHP command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want a simple confirmation:

```
<a href="deletephone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Really delete?\');">Delete Phone</a>
```

[`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) prompts the user and returns true if they say OK, false if they say Cancel.

Comment: Thank you for escaping the apostrophes. Answer worked perfectly. For some reason a similiar function did not work for me.

Comment: @gamerzfuse: Glad that worked! It's easy to forget the `return`, maybe that was what wasn't working before, who knows.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `onclick` attribute of the link. If the function returns `false`, the link will not proceed.

```
<a href="deletephone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete Phone</a>
```

Here, the `confirm()` function will return `true` if the user pressed OK, and `false` if the user pressed Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
<a href="deletephone.php?id='. $row['id'].'" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this ?');">Delete Data</a>
```